# Memory efficient data loading with Dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Well, what I have is a big CSV file with data and a bottleneck of server RAM. Besides that, there is a dask-distributed cluster that looks like a solution for this case, dask-scheduler is running on the server. Theres what I have tried:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask.bag import from_sequence

cheques = dd.read_csv('cheque_data.csv') # not working because of distributed workers can't access file directly
cheques = from_sequence(pd.read_csv('cheque_data.csv',chunksize=10**4)).to_dataframe() # dask Bag from_sequence constructs from tuples or dict
```

So I have stucked here, any ideas and clues would be great

Comment: Another option could be `vaex`, https://vaex.io/.

Comment: Why not run a local cluster on the same machine where the data file is? Or not use distributed at all?

Comment: @mdurant, the main RAM and calculating resource is remote and running dask-worker

Comment: If your worker cannot access the file directly, you need to come up with something yourself - shared disc, cloud storage...

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet says `dd.read_csv('cheque_data.csv')` is "not working because of distributed workers can't access file directly".

I think you need to give your workers access to the file.

I prefer splitting up huge files before they're read by Dask.  That makes it easier for Dask to read the files in parallel.

It depends on the size of `cheque_data.csv`.  2GB is a lot easier to manage than 30GB.